# Function that detects repetitions

Tags: function-construction

I have a large list of 2-tuples and I need a function that lists first values that have at least one repeated second value.
Small example:

```
Function[{{"name1",4},{"name2",5.4},{"name7",4},{"name9",-3},
   {"name11",4},{"name6",-3},{"name15",4.1}] =
 {"name1","name7","name9","name11","name6"}
```

How to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to solve your problem.  First, let

```
list1 = {{"name1",4},{"name2",5.4},{"name7",4},{"name9",-3},{"name11",4},
         {"name6",-3},{"name15",4.1}};
```

then

```
Sort[Transpose[Catenate[Select[GatherBy[list1, Last], Length[#] > 1 &]]][[1]]]
```

I don't know if that is efficient enough for you, but will be interested to see how it compares with other proposed solutions.

Comment: Thank You, your solution runs the fastest among others.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{"name1", 4}, {"name2", 5.4}, {"name7", 4}, {"name9", -3}, {"name11", 4},
     {"name6", -3}, {"name15", 4.1}};
```

You can also use `Counts` and `Cases`:

```
counts = Counts[list[[All, 2]]];
Cases[{a_, _?(counts[#] > 1 &)} :> a] @ list
```

> {"name1", "name7", "name9", "name11", "name6"}

And an alternative way to use `GatherBy` + `Select` combination:

```
list[[Join @@ 
  Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @
    GatherBy[Range @ Length @ list, list[[#, 2]] &], 1]]
```

> {"name1", "name7", "name11", "name9", "name6"}

Answer (score 6):

Applying `GroupBy` to your test list:

```
GroupBy[testlist, Last -> First]
```

> <|4 -> {"name1", "name7", "name11"}, 5.4 -> {"name2"}, 
>     -3 -> {"name9", "name6"}, 4.1 -> {"name15"}|>

It remains to select values with the length larger than one. This can be done, for example like this:

```
func2[l_] := Flatten[Values[Select[GroupBy[l, Last->First], (Length[#]>1)&]]]

func2[testlist]
```

> {"name1", "name7", "name11", "name9", "name6"}

Same concept as a composition of functions:

```
func = Flatten@*Values@*Select[GreaterThan[1]@*Length]@*GroupBy[Last->First]
```